# Pointers on image indicating geographic location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an world map image as below and I need to put some random location pointers on it.To select a point on map,I created separate div pointers to handle.

Such as :

`<div id="div1" class="div-map-icon" style="left: 283px; top: 136px;"></div>`

and div-map-icon class

```
.div-map-icon{
  background-image: url(../images/map_icon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 26px;
  position: absolute;

  float: left;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Current Output:

[image]

However when i tried to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/ .Its not reflecting in IE10.

Any help will be highly helpful?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't reflect your question. There is no div with a class of div-map-icon? Also to get your animation to work in IE you need to provide CSS3 properties that it supports instead of just -webkit- prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the animation `pulsate` to work in IE you either need to use the `-ms-` browser prefix or native CSS3 properties to get it to work like in this example:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Fy8vD/852/**

**CSS**

```
.gps_ring {
    border: 3px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:214px;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    opacity: 0.0
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}

@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
}
```